# Unable to save item (large mp4 file)

Tags: cme, web8.5, sdl-tridion, multimedia, binary

I am trying to create a Multimedia Component in SDL Web 8.5:

- Multimedia type: mp4
- File size: 860 MB

Uploading the file works fine, but while saving the item it gives the below error:

[image]

Steps taken:

1. Added the following code in `web.config` file located under `\WebUI\WebRoot`

   ```
   <system.web>
     <httpRuntime  executionTimeout="100000" maxRequestLength="1073741824" />
   </system.web>

   <system.webServer>
      <security>
         <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824"/>
         </requestFiltering>
      </security>
   ```
2. Increased the maximum upload size in IIS to 1073741824 from IIS manager and restarted the IIS.

Can you tell the solution for the above problem?

**Stacktrace from Event Viewer:**

> Error downloading file 'FS_e082b44d-f4e7-4265-b25f-3420199703d6' from 'FileSystemBinaryContentStorage'. See inner exception for more details.
>   Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService
Errorcode: 854
User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

```
StackTrace Information Details:
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value)
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.Stream.InternalCopyTo(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.FileSystemBinaryContentStorage.WriteContentToStream(Uri uri, Stream outStream)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.FileSystemBinaryContentStorage.WriteContentToStream(Uri uri, Stream outStream)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.SetBinaryContent(BinaryContent binaryContent)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Component.OnSaved(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.Save(Boolean checkInAfterSave)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.Save()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceBase.Save(IdentifiableObjectData deltaData, ReadOptions readBackOptions)
   at SyncInvokeSave(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Answer (score 4):

Can you go to the Event Viewer on the CM server and grab the entire stack trace for this error?

Couple of thoughts:

1)System.OutOfMemoryException seems would be due to lack of actual system memory, despite your config changes. Look up generic Windows reasons and remedies for this.

2) error states "error downloading file...from FileSystemBinaryContentStorage", this hints that it's during the process of when the server downloaded it from your browser, saved it to a temp file system location (to a temp folder) and then attempted to buffer it in RAM in prep for writing into the CM database and ran out of available RAM. On the latter, check your SQL Server/Oracle DB swap space/page memory config to ensure the DB temp memory is sufficient. But also look at what memory your Windows server has.

3) submit a ticket to SDL Support right away. They might already have the specific resolution documented in their knowledge base.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Nickoli suggested, should try checking and possibly increasing the sendTimeout attribute value of web.config to 10 minutes, as discussed in KB article https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000004380